# Error printing a vector with names

Tags: c++, vector

I have a vector named "list" and I want to print the names that are in the list but it says

> operator "<<" matches these operand
>
> operand types are: std::ostream << std::string

Why do I have this error and how cand I fix it?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<algorithm>


using namespace std;
vector<string> list;

vector<string> getAll() {     //I tried to use this function instread of "list"(list is used below) but it's the same result.
    return list;
}


int main() {

    list.push_back("Ion");
    list.push_back("Gabi");
    list.push_back("Sabrina");

    for (string i : list) 
        std::cout << i;           //HERE
    
    }
```

Comment: `#include <string>`

Comment: is there any reason `vector<string> list;` is a global variable?

Comment: Bad name for a vector, too

Comment: You don't need `algorithm` header. Also, `for(string i : list)` should be `for(string& i : list)` not to make a copy of each element of the list.

Answer (score 3):

You did not `#include <string>`. It is important.

Yes, I know you were able to instantiate the vector without it. No, that doesn't make a difference. It's pure chance, down to how your standard library implementation is laid out.

The function responsible for making `<<` work on strings is inside that header.

Answer (score 0):

You have missed to add library for string, include it, by `#include <string>`. The header `<string>` also declares the stream inserter.